# How can we implement a CREATOR in an abstract class?

Tags: java, android, service

is there a way to implement a CREATOR in the parent-class (abstract). I am building my service and exporting it to other application to use, so I dont have any information about the child classes that will extends my abstract parent.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

thanks

Comment: you can't. the `CREATOR` has to be implemented in the Children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CREATOR` field is used to help instantiate `Parcelable` classes.  An abstract class can't be instantiated, so it doesn't make sense to have one for it.  Each subclass needs to provide their own `CREATOR`.